# Disable weekends on checkbox checked and enable back when unchekced

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all I have tried the following code to enable/disable weekends of datepicker as follows but not working as expected what I need is I would like to disable when checkbox was checked and enable when un-checked. Also if there is any server side event for checkbox I would like to perform

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".ui-datepicker-current").datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'http://reginasoccer.com/images/calendar.gif'
            });
            $('.ui-button').click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(".ui-datepicker-current").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
                } else {
                    $(".ui-datepicker-current").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
<div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWeekend" CssClass="ui-button" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSelectedDate" CssClass="ui-datepicker-current" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 0):

You need to Write the `Check_BoxChanged` Event on the `Checkbox` . if Checkbox is checked , try to disable the `asp:Textbox`  which inturns diables the `DatePicker`

**update:**

Try to Keep your jquery code in a method and call it in server side

```
function myFun(){
 $(".ui-datepicker-current").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
}
```

In your Checkbox change event call the function as follows:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "calling", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFun();</script>", false);
```

Here is the Client side implementation

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/xg1d2ryr/)

Comment: I don't want to disable the datepicker I need to disable weekends

Comment: @Nithya got it .check my new updte

Comment: @Nithya try to change it with `RegisterScriptBlock`

Comment: Hi currently I don't have any server side event on client side have written do I need to still add the script block

Comment: @Nithya i didnt get you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143527/discussion-between-webruster-and-nithya).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it we need to provide `option` and the code is as follows

```
$("#chkWeekend").change(function () {
          if ($("#chkWeekend").is(':checked')) {
                $("input[id$='txtSelectedDate']").datepicker('option', { beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
          }
         else {
            $("input[id$='txtSelectedDate']").datepicker('option', { beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.Weekends })
                }
            })
```